# Is possible to have switch in switch?

Tags: c++, c, switch-statement

is this valid C code ? Is possible to have switch in switch ?

```
switch (i){
 case 1:
  switch(c){
   case 1:
    c = 0;
    break;
   case 3:
    c = 5;
    break;
   }
case 2:
 // another code
}
```

Comment: Yes, why should that not be valid?

Comment: Why don't you test it?

Comment: Why not try it? (yes)  If it gets confusing, move the nested switches to another function.

Comment: You should add a break before case 2, unless you want the code for case 2 to be executed too.

Comment: @MM. What bugs me with "Why don't you test it?" replies on *C/C++* questions is that tests are unreliable with those languages.

Comment: @MM Just because it compiles doesn't mean it would be valid C code.

Comment: @Lucas: (1) C and C++ compilers have incompatibilities with standard, but I don't think switch/case is one of them.  (2) Recent compilers such as recent gcc/clang versions strongly obey standard drafts, just a test is a good observation to see the possibility of a syntax.  (3) Otherwise, we should doubt every aspect of a code against standard and whole of day waste our time to read drafts. I prefer do a test (4) I asked _"why...?"_, he can for example answers "I tested, it's possible, but I doubt it's cross compiler or not...". It doesn't harm to ask as a comment. is it?

Comment: I think the worst piece of code I actually shipped consisted of 8x3x3x3 nested switches.  Crunch makes you do some silly things sometimes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, to have switch in switch is valid.

§ 6.4.2 **The switch statement**

> 4 **Switch statements can be nested**; a case or default label is associated with the smallest switch enclosing
>   it.

Comment: Documented answer are always the best, always.

Answer (score 4):

### Yes

C++ § 6.4.2 / 4

> Switch statements can be nested; a case or default label is associated
>   with the smallest switch enclosing it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can have `switch` within  a `switch` statement.